# How to access mysql of my Webhost from Command Promt

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

Is it possible to connect `mysql` of my webhost from `cmd` on my pc, in the same way as I am connecting to mysql installed on my localhost using XAMPP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes its possible to connect to MySQL on web host. MySQL runs on port number 3306. You need to check if the web host has this port open. if not you can request your hosting provider to get it opened. Once its done you can connect to MySQL as you do on localhost May be you need to add privileges to user account to connect from remote machine(your localhost IP).

Other option would be to use PhpMyAdmin.

Comment: Yes 3306 port is opened. What are the commends to connect on remote server. At localhost, I just use `mysql- u abc -p` and it establishes the connection.

Comment: add -h hostName to it. ie `mysql -u userName -p -h hostName`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to download and install the Windows MySQL client 
http://www.mysql.com/downloads/installer/

After installation, make sure the mysql executable is in your cmd PATH.

You need to specify the hostname or IP address of the server with the -h parameter.

```
mysql -u username -p -h myhost.example.com
```